# Vertex AI API. Fine tuning the chat model

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to launch Vertex AI fine tuning.
I have followed the tutorial step by step:

1. Created storage
2. Uploaded dataset in .jsonl format
3. Configured the model details etc.

One entry in my dataset file (jsonl) looks as follows:

> {"messages": [{"author": "user", "content": "Tell a joke about
> flovers"}, {"author": "assistant", "content": "Roses are red, Violets
> are blue. I have a gun. Get in the van."}]}

When I hit "start tuning" button nothing happens. The manual says I should see the process in the pipelines window, but I see nothing there. I thought maybe my dataset is corrupted and tried also to use the sample dataset provided with the tutorial.Same thing- tuning process is not starting.
What am I missing here?

[image]

Update:

I was able to fix the problem above.All I had to do was to enable all the related APIs. It is weird that GCP doesn't provide any kind of warning during fine tuning startup.
[image]

Now, I have the fine tune pipeline job running but failing with the following error:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details by sharing the tutorial you are following?

Comment: I can't really find a way to copy link but this tutorial is located on the right side bar of "Create a tuned model " page in GCP. If you open that page you see the tutorial.

Comment: Do these[link1](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/start/quickstarts/quickstart-tuning#generative-ai-tune-model-console) and [link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4A4W03qUTsw) help you?If not, could you elaborate your question by providing details to replicate the problem?

Comment: @kiranmathew Yes, I am performing all those steps exactly. When clicking "start tuning" nothing happens. Now, I on  Free trial with : $400.00 credit from Google. Is it possible the training is not part of the trial?Though I receive no warnings or errors in the console.

Comment: I fixed it. It appears not all the related APIs have been enabled. I was working trough the setup based on the tutorial manually enabling APIs. But the things is, I haven't enabled all of them. On the Vertex AI main page there is a blue buttons "enable all recommended APIs". Once I hit it,the fine tuning setup started working.

Comment: @kiranmathew  updated with the new problem in this task

Comment: Can you take a look at this [link](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/AI-ML/Vertex-AI-fine-tuning-LLM-model/m-p/611982/highlight/true).Is it possible for you to try in the `us-central1` region?You can check the regions available of the resource in the Quotas page within your project. go to "IAM & Admin" > "Quotas" then go find the resource at the search bar.

Comment: I have found several resources on which fine tuning depends are zero. I have requested quota increase for those. waiting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posting the above comments as an answer to help community members in their research.*

**Issue 1**:When trying to launch Vertex AI fine tuning chat model by clicking the "start tuning" button nothing happens.

**Solution:** The above issue was solved after enabling API’s.On the Vertex AI main page there is a blue button "enable all recommended APIs". Once  it clicked,the fine tuning setup started working.

**Issue 2:**  Error message:`code=RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED`

**Solution:** This type of error generally happens when the requested resource is not in that region or reaches the maximum quota. We can check the regions available of the resource in the Quotas page within your project. go to "IAM & Admin" > "Quotas" then go find the resource at the search bar.

For more information refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/start/quickstarts/quickstart-tuning#generative-ai-tune-model-console),[link2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4A4W03qUTsw) and [link3](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/resources).

Posting the answer as ***community wiki*** for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.